# UTF-8 Ignored by enctype="multipart/form-data" for Form submit when handling Chinese charactors

Tags: java, utf-8, multipartform-data, apache-commons-fileupload

In JSP:
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>

In Servlet:
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

```
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        List items = upload.parseRequest(aaReq);
        Iterator iterator = items.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext())
        {
            FileItem item = (FileItem) iterator.next();
            System.out.println(item .getString("UTF-8").trim());

        }
```

I am getting weird charactors. I have searched all over the web, not able to find the solution, please help. BTW i am using Websphere7.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above works for Chinese. I made some silly error elsewhere.